# How can I run matlab m file with arguments and handle that argument in m file?

Tags: matlab, command-line-arguments, octave

How can I run a matlab m file with arguments?
I can run the same code in octave with arguments but I could not find the **corresponding code in matlab**.
After running the m file on command line with arguments, I need to handle that argument in m file.
Here is the corresponding octave code that works perfectly:

```
#! /usr/bin/octave -qf

argList = argv();
```

Here is the command that run the above m file perfectly:

```
./solver.m this_is_argument_of_m_file
```

***What is the corresponding matlab codes?***

**Update:**
***By command line, I mean the operating system command line(terminal, windows cmd), not the matlab command line.***

Comment: matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "solver.m 'arg1(string)';exit"

Answer (score 0):

You should know that there's a difference between scripts and functions. The Mathworks had dedicated a part of the [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) to this difference.

Script do not take input arguments, functions can, but don't need to.
You can recognize a function as the first functional code in the m-file is `function`. A function uses its own workspace, a script uses matlab's base workspace.

For example:

```
function out = fcn_name(in1, in2, varargin)
```

Furthermore, You can program using OO in matlab, but I think you should start reading the link above.

For startup command please check the [this](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html) part of the documentation. You may want to use the `-r` option.

Comment: OK, I understood that part thanks. Now I want to correct my question. By command line, I mean the operating system command line(terminal, windows cmd), not the matlab command line. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the windows cmd prompt, you can run it as follows:

```
"C:\PATH_TO_MATLAB\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "run('C:\PATH_TO_M-FILE\mfile.m');"
```

This will leave matlab running; it can then be closed by using the `exit` command.

The same approach may be taken on linux:

```
./PATH_TO_MATLAB/matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nodesktop -r < /PATH_TO_M-FILE/mfile.m
```

Some versions of matlab seem to object to having the '.m' part there - if it throws an error, try removing the extension...

In response to your comment, Linux only (I don't have a windows installation to try it on), this can be accomplished best if you configure your system such that you can run matlab simply by typing `matlab` into your terminal. You can set this up by creating a symlink (`sudo ln -s PATH_TO_MATLAB_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/`). Then run in terminal:

```
cd PATH_TO_FUNCTION_YOU_WANT && matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nodesktop -r 'mfile(args)'
```

Make sure you don't include the `.m`, everything in the quotes is passed straight to matlab. You can include more than one function if you separate them with semicolons. I have no idea how passing strings as arguments works though...

Comment: Where is the argument parameter of this command? U just ran the m file. There is no argument. This is not i am looking for.

Comment: @ Celik I have updated the solution to account for this - I hadn't fully understood your question.

Comment: The MATLAB program is now much more simple to use from the command line. Use `matlab -batch 'function(42, "string")'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set parameters, and get the script to pick them up. Here is an example from a *.m file of mine...

```
if ~exist("seq", "var")
  seq = "ball";
else
  seq = strtrim(seq);
endif 

if ~exist("scale", "var")
  scale = 30.0
end
```

If the variables are undefined, the script assigns a default value. In the first case this is a string, and we clip off any dangling whitespace from the supplied argument. In second case it is a float value. I have not checked for data types, but Octave / Matlab should handle that.

You can (sort-of) pass arguments to myScriptFile.m like this...

```
seq = "fish"; scale = 10.0; myScriptFile
```

This is not as neat as passing named arguments. The values persist and may interfere with your next call if you don't keep your wits about you. But it is fine for rapid prototyping. Much of my stuff never makes it into a product, and the bits that do need tidying up anyway. It is what it is.

Comment: Op wants to run a MATLAB script from the system’s command prompt (= terminal), and pass command line arguments. Your way to pass arguments to a script works, but you should really be using functions instead.

Comment: Possibly. But Octave is handy for rapid prototyping of scripts like this. When I have something that works, I can turn it into a nice function for general use.